# how can I randomly place dynamically created buttons?

Tags: java, android, button

I'm dynamically creating buttons for my app and I want to position them randomly on the screen.
I'm trying to position them using linear layout method `setMargins` :

Button creation is inside `onCreate`:

```
    // Create buttons
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_BUTTONS; i++) {
        Button hiddenButton = new Button(this);
        // Set new button properties
        hiddenButton.setId(i);
        hiddenButton.setOnClickListener(setOnClick(hiddenButton));
        // Add the button to the array of buttons
        buttonsArr[i] = hiddenButton;

    }
```

And I have this function to place them randomly:

```
private void placeButtonsOnScreen() {

    Random r = new Random();

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ordered_buttons_layout);

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_BUTTONS; i++) {
        final Button hiddenButton = buttonsArr[i];
        // Get random horizontal margin for the button
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        horizontalMargin = r.nextInt(Math.abs(SCREEN_WIDTH
                - hiddenButton.getWidth()));
        layoutParams.setMargins(horizontalMargin, 50, 0, 0);
        // Add the button to the screen
        layout.addView(hiddenButton, layoutParams);
        Log.d("button width", String.valueOf(hiddenButton.getWidth()));
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `getWidth()` function return 0. What should I do in order to place the buttons in the screen without getting cut off by the sides of the screen (i.e subtracting the button's width)?

Comment: when do you call placeButtonsOnScreen()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only get the view dimensions after the layout pass, so where you call placeButtons instead call:

```
    getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            placeButtons();
            getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
```

Update :

```
    int btnCount = 10;
    final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.action_bar);
    for (int i = 0; i < btnCount; i++) {
        layout.addView(new Button(this),new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
    layout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

            for(int i = 0; i<layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View view = layout.getChildAt(i);
                if(view instanceof Button) {
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                    int horizontalMargin = r.nextInt(Math.abs(SCREEN_WIDTH - view.getWidth()));
                    layoutParams.setMargins(horizontalMargin, 50, 0, 0);
                    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    layout.requestLayout();
```

Comment: what is the getViewTreeObserver? It doesn't recognize that function

Comment: `final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ordered_buttons_layout);
  layout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
    new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

     @SuppressLint("NewApi")
     @Override
     public void onGlobalLayout() {
      placeButtonsOnScreen();
      layout.getViewTreeObserver()
        .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
     }
    });`

But in the log i still see that the size of `hiddenButton.width()` is 0

Comment: You have to add the buttons to the layout, it has no size without parent.

Comment: So how do you suggest to write it?

Comment: No.. :( :( :( ... all I see is a blank page with no buttons... the app does respond because the timer is running and return back to the main page

Comment: OHH forget about that last comment, it was my bad, it works!!!!
Thanks a lot my friend!